# Structure PHP array to pass to JS correctly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, mongodb

This works when we do this:

```
$db = $connection->messages;
$collection = $db->messagesCollection;
$messageArray = $collection->find(array('IDto' => '4'));
foreach($messageArray as $messageData){
    $messageFrom = $messageData['IDfrom'];
    $messageTo = $messageData['IDto'];
    $messageTitle = $messageData['messageTitle'];
    $messageIfRead = $messageData['ifRead'];    
}

$JSONData = array('true', $messageFrom, $messageTo, $messageTitle, $messageIfRead); 
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($JSONData).")";
```

But when we do this:

```
$db = $connection->messages;
$collection = $db->messagesCollection;
$messageArray = $collection->find(array('IDto' => '4'));
$JSONData = array('true', $messageArray); 
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($JSONData).")";
```

and in the Javascript  do this:

```
$.getJSON("mySite.com/pullData/getMail.php?callback=?",{
request: requestVar},
function(recievedData) {
    alert(recievedData);
})
```

We get an alert of `true, [object Object]`
When using console log we get `Object {}`

How do we send that table data correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your biggest problem is the `MongoCursor`:

```
$messageArray = $collection->find(array('IDto' => '4'));
$JSONData = array('true', $messageArray); 
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($JSONData).")";
```

You are trying to encode an object of `MongoCursor` there, hence the string representation is `[object Object]`.

Try:

```
$messageArray = $collection->find(array('IDto' => '4'));
$JSONData = array('true', iterator_to_array($messageArray)); 
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($JSONData).")";
```

Instead. All `find` functions in MongoDB return a `MongoCursor`, the reason why your first code works is because you iterate the cursor building up your objects:

```
foreach($messageArray as $messageData){
    $messageFrom = $messageData['IDfrom'];
    $messageTo = $messageData['IDto'];
    $messageTitle = $messageData['messageTitle'];
    $messageIfRead = $messageData['ifRead'];    
}
```

Note as well that the default `json_encode` of a document will contain objects, such as `MongoId` and `MongoDate` that do not encode too well into reusable JSON syntax. As such you will need to handle these types yourself.

#### Edit

Maybe a better way is to actually redo the indexes manually:

```
$messageArray = $collection->find(array('IDto' => '4'));
$d = array();
foreach($messageArray as $row){
    $d = $row;
}

$JSONData = array('true', $d); 
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($JSONData).")";
```

This way you will have a `0` based incrementing index instead of the ObjectId as each index base.

Comment: Ok now i'm getting all of the data as objects, how to I grab them from the brackets from their array key like receivedData[1]['IDFrom']? right now it looks like this : http://i46.tinypic.com/2j5xdau.png

Comment: @Silas What you can do is (since I noticed your using JQuery): `$.each(recievedData, function(i, item){ console.log(item._id.$id); });` You might wanna pull out the indexes manually though unless those object id indexes work ok with your application.

Comment: this is awesome! it's starting to work. Thanks a bunch for your time. is there a way I can "foreach" this in javascript/jquery so I can handle multiple rows?

Comment: recievedData[1]['userIdTo'] when i do that, I get the proper response for one row. How do I get the other rows that come through?

Comment: @Silas Sorry didn't read fully. The sample code I showed in my first comment will work with both versions of the array and will loop each row with the `item` variable being the row. To get more rows you simply change the `1` to something else like `2`, or you can use the loop I showed earlier.

Comment: @Silas Ha correction to the code I gave you for the loop: `$.each(recievedData[1], function(i, item){ console.log(item._id.$id); });` should be accessing index one there for the var since the data is actually in position 1